# Unexpected empty object pattern no-empty-pattern

Tags: node.js, reactjs

I am getting this error:

```
Unexpected empty object pattern no-empty-pattern
```

in this code

```js
const Login = () => {
    const[{} ,dispatch] = useStateValue()

    const signIn = () => {
        auth.signInWithPopup(provider)
        .then(result => {
            dispatch({
                type: actionTypes.SET_USER,
                user: result.user
            })
        })
        .catch(error => alert(error.message))
    }
```

Comment: Try `const[{type, user} ,dispatch] = useStateValue()`. See https://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-empty-pattern

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what `useStateValue` is supposed to do, but this line doesn't parse:

```
    const[{} ,dispatch] = useStateValue()
```

perhaps you meant:

```
    const [value, dispatch] = useStateValue({})
```